# In React, how to make <p> tag emulate the behavior of <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have an entire React app built with adding navigation to onClick method of `<p>` tag, for example: `<p onClick={()=>history.push('/contact-us')}>Contact Us</p>` (as I didn't want page reload on navigation, something which is expected from SPA). Now the client wants options on right click which the browser provides by default for `<a>` tag [(like open link in new tab, open link in incognito, see image for more details)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fB6O.png). **How can I achieve this by making least amount of change to my code base?** The last thing that I would want to do is replace all `<p onClick={}>` with `<a>` tag.

Comment: I would say replacing your `p` tags with `a` shouldn't be the last thing that you want to do but actually be the preferred approach. You could look at writing codemods to ease this process but having `p` tags with `onClick` instead of using anchor tags has other implications. For example, when server side rendering (if you have that), your links would not be functional until all JS code is downloaded, parsed and executed.

Comment: I was looking for something like component prop in mui [see here](https://mui.com/guides/composition/) or role="button" in bootstrap, can we do something like this here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an  tag, it is better to use `<NavLink>` for links. This behaves like a normal `<a>` tag but also does not reloads the page (as expected from a SPA).

As for opening the link in a new tab, add these attributes to your  :
`target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"`. This will open the link in a new tab.

More on that here: [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-html-to-open-link-in-new-tab/#:~:text=The%20target%20attribute%20set%20to,depending%20on%20the%20browser's%20settings](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-html-to-open-link-in-new-tab/#:%7E:text=The%20target%20attribute%20set%20to,depending%20on%20the%20browser%27s%20settings)

Answer (score 0):

Use Link tag you can import from react-router-dom library i.e.,

```
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 <Link to={'/contact-us'}>Contact Us</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a components that you could customize however you like.

have a look below

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Link, useSearchParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import usestate from '@alentoma/usestate';

export const parseLink = (to: string, args?: any[], encryptedArgs?: any[], clean?: boolean) => {
    var url = to;
    args?.forEach(x => {
        var str = (x ?? "").toString();
        if (clean)
            str = x.replace(/[ ]/gmi, "-");
        
        str = encodeURI(str.replace(/\?/gmi, ""));
        url = str.uri(url)
    });
    encryptedArgs?.forEach(x => {
        // encrypt the string you will have t implement this on you own if you use it
        var item = HttpClient.enscriptString(x).toString();
        url = item.uri(url);
    })
    return url;
}

export default ({ clean, className, title, to, children, args, encryptedArgs, onClick, disablenavigation }: { disablenavigation?: boolean, onClick?: Function, clean?: boolean, className?: string, title?: string, to: string, children?: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[], args?: string[], encryptedArgs?: string[] }) => {
    const state = usestate({
        path: "",

    })
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        state.path = parseLink(to, args, encryptedArgs, clean);
    }, [])

    return (
        <a className={className} onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (onClick != undefined) {
                onClick();
            }
            if (disablenavigation !== true)
                navigate(state.path);
            return false;
        }} title={title} href={state.path}>
            {children}
        </a>
    )
}
```

Now you could simple do.

```js
<EncryptedLink to='/detail' args={["405"]} title='test title'>
                    <p>
                        Home
                    </p>
</EncryptedLink>

// You could also add click event and navigaion at the same times
<EncryptedLink to='/detail' args={["405"]} onClick={dosomething} title='test title'>
                    <p>
                        Home
                    </p>
</EncryptedLink>

// You could also disable navigation and add click event instead
<EncryptedLink to='/detail' args={["405"]} disablenavigation={true} onClick={dosomething} title='test title'>
                    <p>
                        Home
                    </p>
</EncryptedLink>
```